# If $\dfrac{\mathrm {circumference}}{\mathrm {diameter}}$ is the same for all circles, does the surface have to be flat?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, pi

Given a two dimensional Riemannian manifold with the property that the ratio of the circumference and the diameter is the same for all circles. What can be said about it? Does it have to be the Euclidean plane with the usual metric?

Comment: The title is uninformative.

Comment: Any suggestions for a better title?

Comment: Rather than "circumference/diameter," say "ratio of circumference to the diameter."

Comment: This is really two questions: (i) If the ratio is constant, is it necessarily $\pi$? (ii) If the ratio is $\pi$ for all circles, is the surface necessarily flat? I think the answer to both questions is "yes", but I can't see how to go about proving them.

Answer (score 2):

Let's agree that a "circle of center $p$ and radius $r > 0$" refers to "the image of the Euclidean circle of radius $r$ in the tangent plane at $p$ under the exponential map", and that the metric is of class $C^{2}$, i.e., smooth enough that the Gaussian curvature is continuous.

If the circumference of a circle of radius $r$ is $2\pi r$ merely for *sufficiently small* circles, the Gaussian curvature is zero. (Sketch of proof: If $K(p) \neq 0$, there exists a circle around $p$ inside which $K$ is bounded away from $0$; the [Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_field) implies that radial geosedics through $p$ don't diverge  like rays in Euclidean space, so the circle has the "wrong" circumference.)

Now we get into nitpicking:

- With the preceding definition of "circles", the answer to the original question is "no"; all you can deduce is that the surface is flat (and perhaps complete, depending on the intent of the question).
- If a "circle" is required to be an *embedded* curve, then "yes": In any complete flat surface other than the Euclidean plane, a circle of sufficiently large radius crosses itself.

It may be of interest to note that if $M$ is a cone with vertex $p$ (not of class $C^{2}$ at $p$), then circles centered at $p$ have circumference proportional to their radius, but the constant of proportionality is $\theta$, the incident angle at the vertex (and $\theta$ can be an arbitrary positive real number).

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not. It depends on the Space curvature.

For very "shallow" $C_2$ smooth patches of circle radius $r$ measured in geodesic polar co-ordinates,the circumference tends to $2 \pi r$. Here negligible or zero Gauss curvature $ K, $ what we call flat Euclidean geometry.

When we write $ |K|\, a^2 = 1 $ for "deeper" patches $ K$  is non-zero, positive or negative.The circumference /boundary length of closed loops are,

in elliptic geometry :

$$ 2 \pi a \;\sin (r/a) < 2 \pi r, $$

in hyperbolic geometry: 
$$ 2 \pi a \; \sinh (r/a) > 2 \pi r, $$

and in Euclidean geometry:
$$  2 \pi r. $$

Example patches are spherical cap, Pringles chips saddle surface and flat disc respectively.

There are similar corresponding formulas for enclosed patch areas.

Gauss Bonnet Theorem and geodesic polar coordinates are the relevant study materials.

Comment: But in neither of your counterexamples is the ratio _constant_. If the ratio is constant (not necessarily $\pi$), is the surface necessarily flat? (I think such a surface is impossible unless the ratio is $\pi$, but I am not an expert in this field.)

Comment: You have a point -- the diameter of a circle is not necessarily well-defined. But the radius is. So let's just re-phrase everything in terms of that. (BTW, please include @TonyK in any reply, so that I get notified.)

Comment: @ TonyK It $is$ a constant. We are talking about boundary of some Riemannian surface, right? What exactly do you mean by its diameter when not referring to the flat case?

Comment: @TonyK: OK, radius of what as you understand? I take it as radius of geodesic circles measuring radial length on a surface in a geodesic polar coordinates system.

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about the boundary of some Riemannian surface. I think the OP is talking about sets of points $C(p,r) = \{x:d(p,x) = r\}$, or _circles_ in the vernacular. If this set of points consitutes a rectifiable closed curve, then its length is the _circumference_.

Comment: The embedding is what OP is now perhaps thinking about. Please mark @ if to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22037/discussion-between-narasimham-and-tonyk).